# Verify if content key Json has exist using Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to know how to check if "novalue" exist
For example:

```
{
    name: "maria",
    city_id: "novalue"
    ....
}
```

How i do this in Vue?
Do it in  `<div v-if="condition">` or function?

Comment: just decode it with `JSON.parse` and test the existence of the value in the JS object

Comment: send me an example

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: its using Vue i can do it in if condition in the div

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case you want to/can use ES7 features:

```
const containsKey = (obj, key ) => Object.keys(obj).includes(key);
```

Implementation example:

```
const someCoolObject = {name: 'Foo', lastName: 'Bar'};

const hasName = containsKey(someCoolObject, 'name');
const hasNickName = containsKey(someCoolObject, 'hasNickName');

console.log(hasName, hasNickName); // true, false
```

For Vue:

Component:

```
{
    methods: {
        containsKey(obj, key ) {
            return Object.keys(obj).includes(key);
        }
    },
    computed: {
        hasName() {
            return this.containsKey(this.someObject, 'name');
        }
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<div v-if="hasName"></div>
```

Comment: My solution was v-if="user.city_id != 'novalue'" :)